# Are there inverse trig compound angle identities?

Tags: trigonometry

There are well known identities for compound angle trigonometry, but I can't find anything for inverse trig compound angles, and haven't been able to derive any myself. Are there identities for:

arcsin(a+b)
arccos(a+b)
arctan(a+b)

And if so, can you show how to derive them?

Comment: $\displaystyle \text{arctan}(u) + \text{arctan}(v) = \text{arctan}\left( ~\frac{u+v}{1 - uv} ~\right).$

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit funny in that seeing a question that involved this identity was what made me wonder about the question.

Comment: @DMMiller FYI, see the table in [Angle sum and difference identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), with it containing values for sums and differences of the $\arcsin$, $\arccos$, $\arctan$ and $\operatorname{arccot}$ of angles.

Comment: $\arctan(b/a) = \Im\log(a+ib)$

Answer (score 1):

As linked in one of the comments, there are indeed [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for inverse functions. The $\arctan$ identity is probably the most commonly used for various reasons (including some applications related to special relativity, of all things). They can be derived from the sum of angle formulas, for example:

$\begin{eqnarray}\tan(\alpha + \beta) & = & \frac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta} \\
\tan(\arctan u + \arctan v & = & \frac{u + v}{1 - uv} \\
\arctan u + \arctan v & = & \arctan \left( \frac{u + v}{1 - uv} \right)\end{eqnarray}$

The identities involving $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ are a bit messier since they involve terms mixing the two function, so you have to apply the Pythagorean identity, e.g. $\sin \arccos u = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \arccos u} = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$.